# How to change/reinstall neural network runtime version?

Tags: neural-networks

I'm trying to run Mathematica on Azure instance with Tesla K80.
Setting `TargetDevice->"GPU"` produces the following set of errors for documentation page of `NetTrain`:
[image: errors 1-3]

First error is intermittent, and so is second. But third one persists, and I'm sure that this is a bug since I've trained all the nets on this GPU!

I'm unsure what exactly is happening here. Steps I've tried, but have failed:

1. Reinstalling Mathematica - doesn't work
2. Installing Mathematica on a new machine - this works till I open my other notebook (containing custom nets) and run `NetTrain` on those nets.
3. [Szabolcs's suggestion] Removing the Paclet/folder `NeuralNetworks` from `C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Wolfram Desktop\12.1\SystemFiles\Components` - this throws a different error:
   [image: error4]
4. Installing Mathematica again on a new instance having no influence of my notebooks - this still throws the wrong runtime loaded error.

#### Update 1 [problem persists]

I downgraded from 12.1.1 to 12.0.0, and saw that above simple `NetTrain` works on GPU! Since nets created using newer versions can not be imported, I tried running `NetTrain` on my nets to train them again, but was greeted by following error:
[image]

And now I have this new error for the above (first image) simple net from documentation page of `NetTrain`:
[image]

#### More on Update 1's error:

`trainingData` is just a list of rules where an image maps to string.

On restarting the kernel, loading `trainingData` and running `NetTrain`
[image]
training proceeds (at least till 1 round).

So naturally I go ahead and add `validationData`, but I get the following error:
[image]

First error claims that `trainingData` contains non-images, however that's not true:
[image]

[image]

[image]

And looking at `$LastInternalError` gives the same output:
[image]

Now, if I run `NetTrain` again - I get the exact error shown in Update 1.

#### Update 2 [problem persists]

This is the error I get on a new Ubuntu 18.04 instance (K80) with Mathematica 12.1.1 installed (with none of my notebooks present on the machine to influence):
[image]

#### Update 3 [problem persists]

This is the error I get on a new Windows instance (K80) with Mathematica 12.1.1 installed (with none of my notebooks present on the machine to influence):
[image]

(Notebook was created using same version - 12.1.1)

#### Update 4 [problem persists]

I got access to a local machine with GTX 1070, the errors of Update 2 are still shown but just like Update 2 it also returns a trained net.

### Conclusion

It turns out that Windows neural network runtime 10600 on Mathematica 12.1.1 doesn't support K80 (actually - has dropped support) at the time of writing.

Comment: As a last resort, you can try to delete the directory `~/.Mathematica/Paclets` when Mathematica is not running. This will remove all versions of it. Unfortunately, I don't know which paclet it is, otherwise I would suggest just deleting the relevant one.

Comment: Thanks, apparently Mathematica doesn't download/fix removed paclets and throws a new error `Get::noopen: Cannot open NeuralNetworks`

Comment: Are you sure you're using the latest drivers and firmware for your GPU card?

Comment: Yes, Azure "Data Science Virtual Machine - Windows 2019" instance comes with the drivers installed. Plus no change (that I've noticed) has happened within Windows pre and post error.

Comment: Did you quit Mathematica before deleting the Paclets directory? Did you remove the entire directory? "Cannot open NeuralNetworks" makes no sense as this is part of the installation ... There may be paclet updates, but there is also a built-in version.

Comment: I did, can you verify the directory: I deleted “NeuralNetworks” folder from “C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Wolfram Desktop\12.1\SystemFiles\Components”